# Can rituals like 'Tila tarpana' be performed on "Ratha sapthami" day?

Tags: rituals, surya, vedic-rituals

What rituals have to be done and what activities/celebrations/rituals should NOT be done and who has to do what on Ratha sapthami day?

Can we perform "Tila tarpana"  on Ratha sapthami day for fathers or fore-fathers who have passed away long back?

Can any celebratory ceremonies like House Warming be performed on Ratha sapthami day? Are there any exclusions for the same?

Comment: No duplicate. It has multiple queries.

Comment: You might find the required answers in the links provided in previous one.

Comment: But I could not find anything related to house warming ceremony and any related exclusions...

Comment: Also I couldn't find regarding `Tila tarpanam` for forefathers apart from Lord Surya argya pradhanam

Comment: I just updated my question in more precisely.

Answer (score 3):

First of all **What is Ratha Saptami?**

The  **Sukla Paksha Sapatami Tithi** day in the **Magha** month is known as the [Ratha Saptami](http://www.drikpanchang.com/festivals/ratha-saptami/ratha-saptami-date-time.html).It is dedicated to the worship of Surya Deva.As per Puranas Surya started illuminating the whole world on this day and hence the day is also called "Surya Jayanti".

In general taking bath during Arunodaya muhurtha(sunrise time) is
 highly auspicious in the entire [Magha](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookview.php?chapnum=12) month.

> The Snaana Kaala should be at Arunodaya to Praatah kaala; it is
>   emphasised that bathing in the waters at the time of Suryodaya would
>   purify even those who are the sinners of Brahma hatya or Suraa paana;
>   any human being irrespective of caste, age or sex could take Maagha
>   Snaanaas.

**What rituals has to do and what activities/ celebrations/ rituals?**

As said before the day is dedicated to Surya Deva.So the activities are related to him only.Following are the 2 highly rewarding & recommended activities for that day:

**1)Arunodaya Snaana**(Bathing during sunrise)

Snaana Mantra-

> *The Snaana Mantra-ada Janma krutam paapam mayaa janmasu Janmasu, Tanmey Rogam cha shokam cha Maakarihantu Saptami/ Yetatjjanmakrutam
>   paapam yaccha janmaantaraarjitam, Manovaakkaayajam yaccha
>   jnaataajnaatey cha ye punah/Iti Sapta vidham paapam  Snaanmey Sapta
>   Saptikey, Sapta Vyaadhi samaayuktam hara Maakari Saptami /* (May the
>   entirety of my sins accumulated in my present and previous births on
>   account of conscious and unconscious acts or those perpetrated by my
>   vocal or mental roots be dissolved on this Makara Saptami and may this
>   Sacred Snaana with my earnest and heartfelt supplications and
>   obeisances to you Surya Deva, in the form of Seven kinds of  Sins and
>   Seven types of Diseases be destroyed for ever!)

**2)Argya Pradana**(water offerings to Sun god accompanied by Mantras):

Arghya Pradana Mantra:

> *Sapta Saptivaha preeta Saptaloka pradeepana, Saptami sahito Deva
>   gruhanaarghya Divaakara/*  (Divaakara! You are affectionate of riding
>   on the chariot drwan by Seven Horses with Seven Names and bestow
>   splendour to Seven Lokaas obviously fond of the numeral of Seven;
>   Bhagavan! may I have the privilege of offering ‘Arghya’ on this
>   Saptami Tithi to mark my reverence

**Is  Tila Tarpana(Pitru Tarpana) a recommended act on Ratha Sapatmai?**

From the second link:

> **Maagha Shukla Bhishmaashtami is obeserved with Bhimoddishya Shraaddha
>   Tarpanaas only by those Grhastis who have children alive; but
>   otherwise considered as compulsory.** But Maagha Shukla Dwadashi is to
>   be noted as significant for Tila Snaana,  Tila Puja to Vishnu, Tila
>   Naivedya,  Tila Taila Deepa Daana, Tila Homa, Tila Daana, and Tila
>   Bhakshana.

So ,as you can see the **Magha Sukla Bhishma Ashtami** is recommended for Pitru Tarpanams.And of course the Magha Amavasya Tarapanams are also considered highly auspicious.But, since nothing is mentioned specifically about doing Tarpanams on Ratha Saptami **it can be assumed that it is not recommended**.

And, about the house warming thing,i can't answer.I can't answer regarding things that are not be done on this day either.So consider this as a partial answer.